# Server performance upgrade for 500 users

Tags: linux, memory, storage, central-processing-unit

I have an application(Moodle platform) with 50 users.
The actual performances of the server are:

- RAM is 2 GB
- Storage is 10 GB
- CPU is AMD 2.1 GHz with 2 Core

The server is hosted in amazon, instance type t3a.small

The actual status of usage of RAM and Storage are:

- RAM 1.8GB
- Storage 8.9GB
- CPU

[image]

**My plan is to have 500 users soon what should I upgrade from those performances?**

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You may run 5000 users with that server or need more resources for 60 users. What is your current resource usage for CPU, RAM and HDD ? Did you calculate a per-user requirement ?

Comment: Observe the peek consumption of cpu, ram, resources with your 50 users, that'll give you a fair idea of if you have to upgrade or no. Also, are the users usage well distributed over time, or is there a peek usage at, say, 6pm .... Can you afford to open for 100 users and see what happens? Can you afford the  risk of 500 users having a slow experience, or can you upgrade and just see? Amazon (and the like) usually offer scalable solutions.

Comment: @Overmind I just updated the question!

Comment: @e2-e4 I have updated the question. I can not afford to open 100 users for a moment to check the status of the server performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have 4-5 checkpoints and measure your stats. Say 1 user, 5 users, 10 users, 25 and 50 users. If you’ll see simple dependency you can estimate would 500 users fit in or how many gigs of RAM you need to throw in to make everyone happy.

Comment: Thanks, @BaronSamedi1958 good idea. I will try it!

Comment: Good luck buddy!